# Is there any advantage to giving a customer both a .jpg and a .pdf?

Tags: pdf, jpg

I sell vector prints online. I have noticed that most of my competitors include 2 files with their sales - both a .jpg and a .pdf. The files are supposed to be scaleable. To my mind only a .pdf is needed. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right. But including two types of file format one of them is a JPG is preferable for some reasons

1. for the online database on where you sell your work it is harder to parse the PDF and show its content online. I think it will be a long code specially with the pdf files that contains vector artworks. so it is easier to upload with the PDF the JPG file, so the user can see what he is going to buy.
2. when your customer download the files, the PDF file will not show a thumbnail on his system depend on the client setting most of them them don't have the codec needed to see the PDF thumbnails on their system finder or system explorer, that's why the jpg file will be useful in that case.